# How to change the default user group's name in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I guess this question is more like can I use a single word as the default AD user group for users (currently it is "AD\Domain Users").

If I can, I would like to use something like "users" or similar. How could I do that?

Comment: With all due respect, this is a bad idea.

Comment: Why would be this a bad idea?

Comment: Well first of all you couldn't rename Domain Users to Users, because there's already a group named Users. Secondly, AD and countless other AD-integrated applications simply depend on a very basic modicum of predictability in the structure of an Active Directory and would fail when "Domain Users" was nowhere to be found. AD itself might even fail because who would ever do something like rename the Domain Users group. Even if you could technically drive a car with your feet, that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: Please let me reiterate that there already *is* a default users security group named "Users".

Comment: Do you know another way of having a simple group on my unix/MacOS boxes as the default user group?

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you trying to solve with this? As Ryan points out, so succinctly, this is not a good idea at all.

I can't think of a single case where there would be a benefit to changing this name, so instead of messing with a well-known built-in group for no reason, you should just leave it be.

Comment: I am just curious how could I avoid that this string shows up in my home directory on MacOS. Instead of having a name which has a backslash and a space in it I would like to see a single English word there. I am curious how can I achieve it. There might be a better way of assigning a group to the users and configure the system to use that group when you are creating a folder or a file in Unix/MacOS. Let me know if you have a good link what I should read about this.